# backbone.js data linking

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I'm trying to link an input, a model, and a dom element.

```
<div data-carName="Isetta">
  <input type="textfield" name="speed"/>
  <br />
  <br />
  Speed: <br />
  <div>{speed}</div>
</div>

var Isetta = {
  speed:speedval
}
```

What do I do if I want whenever the card speed input is changed, for the speed dom element to change with it, and the javascript object/model to change as well?

I can do this easily with jQuery data-linking. How do I do it with backbone.js?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also want to consider binding keystroke events and timers to the input field so that when a user has finished typing in their input, you trigger an event on the model that then updates the view:

If you add `id=name` to that field, then in your view you can add something like:

```
events: {
  "keypress #speed"  : "updateViewOnEnter"
},

updateViewOnEnter: function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode != 13) return;
  e.preventDefault();
  this.model.trigger('speed:change');
},
```

Check out this throttle function from Remy Sharp if you want to throttle function calls as a user is still typing in that input field:
http://remysharp.com/2010/07/21/throttling-function-calls/

```
events: {
  "keypress #speed"  : "updateViewOnDelayedKeypress"
},

updateViewOnDelayedKeypress: function(e) {
  throttle(function (e) {
    this.model.trigger('speed:change');
  }, 250));
},
```

Comment: Right on, i've since figured this out

Comment: I think you can also use the "change" event in the second example instead of keypress.

Answer (score 2):

```
var Car = Backbone.Model.extend({ });

var CarView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: Car,
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.bind('change', _.bind(this.render, this));
    }
    render: function() { ... }
}
```

The Car model will generate events, and CarView responds to them.  The list of events is far broader-- and you can add your own, if you like-- than those of data-link.  jQuery Data-Link appears to be concerned entirely with forms, and has a limited filtering mechanism.  It's interesting, but it's clearly tackling a different problem from the one Backbone and other MVC libraries are intended to cover.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check out this library: https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.modelbinding which adds a module that will handle dynamic and convention based binding for you.

Comment: Derick has "abandoned" the project linked above in favor of https://github.com/theironcook/Backbone.ModelBinder and http://www.rivetsjs.com/docs/